# How to calculate a floating point of negative number?

Tags: floating-point

In IEEE double precision n=53. So to represent 16 I can do the following:
The next biggest number from $16=+(.10 \dots 01)_22^5=2^{-1}2^5+2^{-53}2^5=16+2^{-48}$

Now the biggest number from $-16=-16+2^{-49}$, but how to show this formally like i did above for positive $16$ case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IEEE double precision numbers store they sign in a separate bit.  So, (-16) is the same as (+16) except sign-bit changed.  Getting "next" number after (-16) is equivalent to getting "previous" number before (+16) with sign-bit changed.
Next number after (+16) is
$\large+(1.00...01)_2\cdot2^4 = 16\cdot(1+2^{-52}) = 16+2^{-48}$
Previous number before (+16) is
$\large+(1.11...11)_2\cdot2^3 = 16\cdot(1-2^{-53}) = 16-2^{-49}$
Next number after (-16) is
$\large-(1.11...11)_2\cdot2^3 = -16\cdot(1-2^{-53}) = -16+2^{-49}$

Comment: I kind of figured it out already, THANK YOU for the answer. The only thing, everything looks correct but $1$s should be after decimal point, I edited it already :)

Comment: @ASROMA - No, my original message was correct.  Please read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) and get the correct version back.  :-)

Comment: We both were correct since i did not see that your power on 2 was one less than mine :-)